# Algorith which finds shortest path with negative edges and without negative cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Which of the following algorithms finds the shortest path in graphs with negative edges and without negative cycles?
1)Bellman-Ford algorithm
2)Dijkstra's algorithm
3)A* search algorithm
4)Floyd-Warshall algorithm
5)Dijkstra's algorithm with a binary heap

Comment: This is not really the kind of question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow. This site prefers questions that relate to programming _practice_ not theory. For your question a much better site would be [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum. I recommend you move your question there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: When asking about homework
**(1)** Be aware of your school policy: asking here for help may constitute *cheating*.
**(2)** Specify that the question is homework.
**(3)** Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question).
**(4)** Ask about a specific problem with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
[Here](meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

After a search -- Bellman–Ford algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Comment: Other algorithms (in the list) do this as well. But nevertheless, the [open letter to students](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) suggests to help students that show *effort* and have *specific* questions/problems.

Answer (score 0):

For negative edges, but without negative cycle, bellman-ford is preferred if you are finding shortest path from a single source. For all pair Floyd-Warshell can be used. But Dijkstra algo is not used when there is negative edge in a graph.

Could not comment on A* search algorithm. I am not fully aware of it.